# Syntax error JAGSUI: Error parsing model file

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, jags

I'm trying to fit a model in JAGSUI but I get the following error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
> 3 nodes produced errors; first error:
> Error parsing model file:
> syntax error on line 105 near ""

I cannot figure out what's going on here. Below you can find the model code I'm using, up until line 105 (last line) where the error is apearing.

```
sink("model.txt")
```

cat("
model {

```
mu.lpsi.int ~ dnorm(0,0.01)
tau.lpsi.int <- 1/ (sigma.lpsi.int * sigma.lpsi.int)
sigma.lpsi.int ~ dunif(0,10)


#Establishing community level Betas (hyperparameters), 
#Average response of all species for the top covariates
mu.border ~ dnorm(0,0.01)
mu.sec ~ dnorm(0,0.01)
mu.HW ~ dnorm(0,0.01)
mu.PredW ~ dnorm(0,0.01)
mu.PreyW ~ dnorm(0,0.01)

tau.mu.border <- 1/ (sigma.mu.border * sigma.mu.border)
sigma.mu.border ~ dunif(0,10)
tau.mu.sec <- 1/ (sigma.mu.sec * sigma.mu.sec)
sigma.mu.sec ~ dunif(0,10)
tau.mu.HW <- 1/ (sigma.mu.HW * sigma.mu.HW)
sigma.mu.HW ~ dunif(0,10)
tau.mu.PredW <- 1/ (sigma.mu.PredW * sigma.mu.PredW)
sigma.mu.PredW ~ dunif(0,10)
tau.mu.PreyW <- 1/ (sigma.mu.PreyW * sigma.mu.PreyW)
sigma.mu.PreyW ~ dunif(0,10)
```

`#Establishing the Hyperparamaeter for the intercept on detection(p)`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm happy to provide more information. I'm a beginner in JAGS modelling.

Thanks in advance,

Fleur

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the person who asked this question has moved on since it's been 6 months, but for everyone's future reference, I had this same problem (a syntax error near a blank portion of the model file, past the end of the actual model) and solved it by updating R to the newest version.